# How to install Angular 7 Material on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: installation, angular-material, angular7

How to install AngularJS Material on Windows 7 32-bit? I got this error message.

```
C:\Users\Sheik>ng add @angular/material
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Packages are installed through npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install AngularJS Material locally either with [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/npm/info) or [jspm](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/npm/info).

Note: AngularJS Material requires AngularJS 1.4.x to AngularJS 1.7.x. AngularJS Material does not support AngularJS 1.7.1.

**npm**

```
# To install latest formal release  
npm install angular-material

# To install latest release and update package.json 
npm install angular-material --save

# To view all installed packages  
npm list
```

<sub>[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material)</sub>